# How do I redirect a string in Fish?

Tags: fish

I want to redirect a string into the STDIN of a command.

I would do it using something like `cmd <<< "my string"` in Bash, or even `cmd <<EOF ... EOF`. But I can't seem to do either in Fish. What am I supposed to do here? Are pipes the only way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you would use pipes for this, e.g. `echo "my string" | cmd`. fish has no equivalent to the `<<<` operator in bash.

Comment: Can everything done with `<<<` also be done with `|`? I thought `<<<` means "this command expects a file for this particular argument, but I'm going to pass a string instead", and `|` means "this command takes a file as the last argument, so I will omit it and redirect it to the standard input instead."